# How to use my newly installed php 5.4.x in Mac Os (Mountain Lion)?

Tags: php, macos

I just installed php 5.4.7 in my mountain lion system using this guide (http://mac.tutsplus.com/tutorials/server/upgrading-the-native-php-installation-on-os-x-mountain-lion/)
The problem is that when a run a simple php file with the following code :

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

I get information about the old php version (5.3.x).
By the way I already added the /usr/local/bin as the first path of the $PATH variable, so executing php -v at the command line returns the newly installed version (5.4.x)

Any ideas?

PS : The path where I put the files is /Library/WebServer/Documents/PhpProject1

Comment: Do you using MAMP or other complex apps?

Comment: No, I am not using mamp.

Answer (score 1):

I have definetly the same problem. The only difference is that I use Mountain Lion Server.

This solution has worked for me:

http://php-osx.liip.ch/

And then in console:

ln -s /usr/local/bin/php /usr/bin/php

(from https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58343/php-5-4-installation-on-mountain-lion)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1. Install php:

   ```
   curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.4
   ```
2. Make php 5.4 your default version:

   a) Open your paths file.

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/paths
   ```

   b) Change your first line to:

   ```
   /usr/local/php5/bin
   ```